# How do I install the RTL8811au drivers?

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, 20.04, realtek

A long time ago I bought a USB adapter which according to Windows used the RTL8811au chipset. It worked great on Windows 10 and I've never had any problems with it. Yesterday I installed Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS for the first time because I wanted to try something new. The problem is that I just couldn't get the RTL8811au drivers to work. I tried pretty much everything that was answered here and in ubuntuforums since 20.04 was launched and nothing worked for me. I also tried reinstalling Ubuntu and yet nothing.

I'm currently using my phone as USB Ethernet but it's really unpractical. I don't want to switch back to Windows and I don't want to buy another USB adapter.

Output of `lsusb` command:

```
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 005 Device 002: ID 1b3f:2008 Generalplus Technology Inc. USB Audio Device
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 0bda:1a2b Realtek Semiconductor Corp. DISK
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 12d1:1050 Huawei Technologies Co., Ltd. CAM-L03
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 258a:1007 SINOWEALTH Wired Gaming Mouse
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0c45:7603 Microdia USB Keyboard
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Output of `iwconfig` command:

```
lo        no wireless extensions.

enp6s0    no wireless extensions.

usb0      no wireless extensions.
```

Comment: Please edit your question to show the result of the terminal command: `lsusb` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please be certain that all of the prerequisites at their correct versions are installed:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install --reinstall git dkms build-essential
```

Now downlaod and install the correct driver:

```
git clone https://github.com/morrownr/8821cu.git
cd 8821cu
sudo ./install-driver.sh
```

Remove and reinsert the USB wireless device and it should now be working. If not, reboot.

Comment: I did what you told me and after rebooting it's still not working. I'm probably going to use a wi-fi signal repeater and connect an ethernet cable to it but let's keep trying to make this work for future readers.

Comment: Please edit your question to show the result of: `lsmod | grep 8821` and also: `iwconfig` and finally: `dmesg | grep -e wlx -e 8821`

Comment: `lsmod | grep 8821` and `dmesg | grep -e wlx -e 8821` commands did not show any results. Also I updated the output of `lsusb`

Comment: Ok now it suddenly started working, I see WIFI in the settings and it's there. I don't know how to thank you enough...

Comment: Awesome! Glad it’s working as expected.

Comment: The repository moved to `8821cu-20210916`

Answer (score 1):

I have used both RTL8812 and 8814AU and found the Aircrack-ng GitHub to be extremely useful and reliable for both of these drivers on Linux.

Check out both GitHub's below and try compiling the DKMS modules to see if that helps.

RTL8812: https://github.com/aircrack-ng/rtl8812au

RTL8814: https://github.com/aircrack-ng/rtl8814au

Cheers.

Comment: I already tried aircrack-ng/rtl8812au before. I tried aircrack-ng/rtl8814au now by following the instructions in the README.md, it still doesn't work.

Comment: Although aircrack-ng's git is indeed useful, these are not the correct drivers for this 0bda:c811 device. These are not the droids we're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

This just short Tutorial for NEWBIE (like me!) for installing driver USB Wifi driver for Linux Debian and it’s derivatives (Debian, Ubuntu, Linux Mint, Pop! OS, Elementary OS, etc.)

When you're switch to new OS distro or updating OS or accidently delete some part of software sometimes your Wifi driver are no support / no working and got blank your mind ... Yup thats right !

**First STEP to do :**

1. You only need YOUR SMARTPHONES and make sure also they have “Internet Mobile Data”.
2. Then you need to opened “Developer Options” on your smartphone to do that first before.
3. Open your phone “Settings” and find it “About Phone” and selected “Version Number” and then now repeated click up to (7x) seven times.
4. Inside “Developer Options” find it or scrolling to the “Network” and selected “Select USB Configuration” and then select again to the “USB Ethernet (RNDIS)”.
5. After this all you need is USB cable connected to your PC or Laptop and it’s done, now you ready online!

**Second STEP to do :**

1. Installing GDebi (I’m using Geary on Pop! OS that are the same software). You can find GDebi in Ubuntu Software Center,  just search for it and install it from there.
2. Then installing the latest “realtek-rtl88xxau-dkms” deb package from Kali’s repository.
3. After this just type in your linux terminal “sudo reboot” to rebooting your PC or Laptop.
4. It’s done , just try to check it out !

I’m trying many times using this method when i switching to new OS distros or update Linux Kernel. This really saving my times and work to do! Thanks for your time to read this !

**Source :**

- https://http.kali.org/kali/pool/contrib/r/realtek-rtl88xxau-dkms/
- https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/dev-options
- https://itsfoss.com/gdebi-default-ubuntu-software-center/